# Elast alert email_from_field sends message just to one recipient

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastalert

When I use email_from_field option, Elastalert sends message just to one recipient, but there is two recipients. Here is my rule:

```
name: SOD Error recipients
type: frequency

# ES Settings
es_host: elasticsearch
es_port: 9200

index: $INDEX
num_events: 1
timeframe:
    seconds: 30
realert:
  minutes: 0
filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "ServiceName: test_multirecipients"
aggregation:
  seconds: 10
aggregation_key: logger
query_key: logger

#SMTP Settings
smtp_host: "$SMTP_IP"
smtp_port: $SMTP_PORT
smtp_ssl: false
smtp_auth_file: /opt/config/smtp_auth_file.yaml
from_addr: "$SMTP_FROM"
email_format: "html"
email_from_field: "recipients"
# Include certain field inside alert body
include: ["ServiceName", "message", "logger", "recipients"]

alert_text_type: alert_text_only
alert_text: "sometext"

alert_text_args:
  - ServiceName
  - "@timestamp"
  - recipients
  - logger

alert:
- "email"
email:
  - "$SMTP_TO2"
```

I think that trouble can be due format of "recipients" field, but I'm not sure. Here is how it looks:
[image]

I tried another syntax:
[image]

In both cases message always sends to **the first email address in the list** (it can be any email), and the second recipient is ignored. But the second recipient is always listed in recipients inside message in outlook.

[image]

Message came to ByndyuSoftTest email but ByndyuSoft4 ignored

[image]

Message came to ByndyuSoft4 email, but ByndyuSoftTest ignored

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
email_from_field passes as single email address, even if there is more addresses.
This works (alerts.py):

```
if 'email_from_field' in self.rule:
    recipient = lookup_es_key(matches[0], self.rule['email_from_field'])
    if isinstance(recipient, str):
        if '@' in recipient:
            to_addr = recipient.split(',')
        elif 'email_add_domain' in self.rule:
            to_addr = [recipient + self.rule['email_add_domain']]
```